# Impedir zoom no smartphone/tablet com Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, layout-responsivo

Uso Bootstrap 3 em meus projetos e tenho uma dúvida.

Gostaria de saber como impedir o zoom em smartphones e tablets, aquele zoom que é feito com o movimento de "pinça" ou com o duplo toque.

Isto mantendo o comportamento responsivo do Bootstrap, ou seja, a largura da página deve permanecer fixa no mesmo tamanho da tela.

Sei que isso é possível pois há aplicações web por aí (ex: Facebook, Twitter) que também impedem o zoom no mobile.

Comment: Você tem algum código para mostrar suas tentativas?

Comment: Na verdade basta somente o `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">`, não há necessidade de usar `maximum-scale=1`.

Comment: @renan Correto. Achei dois artigos que falam sobre a tag e deixarei aqui para quem interessar: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag e http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode desabilitar as opções de zoom em dispositivos móveis adicionando `user-scalable=no` para a meta tag `viewport`.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Isso desabilita o zoom, sendo assim os usuários só serão capazes de scrollar e seu site vai parecer um pouco mais com uma aplicação nativa. Isso **não** é recomendado para todos os sites, então use com cautela!

Veja mais na [documentação oficial](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

Comment: Perfeito amigo! Muito obrigado. =)